# USB Boot Drive is not being recognized

Tags: boot, usb

I am attempting to install Ubuntu v23.04 over Windows 7 on an old Sony VAIO. I have an 8GB USB flash drive that I am using to do this. The VAIO is not showing the USB in Boot Manager. I have installed the ISO file onto the USB twice with BalenaEtcher and once with Rufus, have enabled booting from external devices in the BIOS, and have set external devices as the highest priority in the boot sequence. There is no option to enable the legacy boot mode.
The VAIO's model number is VGN-SR510G

Comment: You should first eliminate the possibility that your installation media is invalid. First, [verify the ISO](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu) you downloaded to make sure that the file was not corrupted in transit. Then, follow the directions in the [official tutorial to Install Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). If you still can not boot the USB, review the documentation for your computer's motherboard.

Comment: From your description you've not ruled out procedural issues (ie. Ubuntu 23.04 requires updated software for some apps to write the file successfully; but you gave no specifics as to versions of your writer software; & for specific types of ISO writes too as is documented in rufus documentation for example due to size), let alone ISO verification that isn't mentioned. Does the thumb-drive boot on another device? (ie. verify the write there, though it's only a partial test unless the hardware is similar in type). You didn't mention which 23.04 iso (there are many; 2 for desktop, server etc)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem before. Make sure to unplug any USB that is connected to your Laptop whether it is a mouse, keyboard and etc. Then you can try to restart and reboot it with only the USB Flash Drive plugged in. Hopefully it would detect by then.